# 2D texture or cube mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping, textures

I am trying to create a planet(OpenGL and C++), but I don't know how to wrap a picture around the sphere I have created.

I am able to create a solid sphere and I can also draw the grid (Latitude and Longitude) of the planet. My biggest problem now is getting a picture around this sphere or grid.

Does anyone know of a simple to follow tutorial on texture mapping?

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you use `gluSphere();` to draw the planet if you want an easy way to add the texture to the sphere, here's an example code of how to make a sphere with a texture wrapped around it, first you have to declare a new reference to `GLUquadric` (declare this before the `initGl` method)

```
GLUquadric* q;
```

now inside `initGl` method we put the following code:

```
q=gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricNormals(q, GL_SMOOTH);

textureID = LoadTexture("***.bmp");      //put the name of the photo resource file you want to use.
gluQuadricTexture(q , GL_TRUE);
```

inside `DrawGlScene` method we put the following code to draw the sphere and wrap the texture we created around it:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureID);
gluSphere(q , 2 , 30 , 30);     
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: Why are you referring to `initGl` and `DrawGlScene`? It is something specific to your own code, and is hardly helpful to include.

Comment: Also keep in mind that people who are stuck with core profiles (v 3.1 and up) cannot use GLU :)

Comment: I #include <GL/glu.h> but I get the following error undefined reference to `gluNewQuadric' when I compile. I have #include <GL/gl.h> and it works fine drawing the grid, any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2):

The U coordinates are basically being calculated as:

```
U = asin(x) / PI + 0.5
```

And the V coordiates:

```
V = asin(y) / PI + 0.5
```

Here are some easy to understand tutorials on how to implement cube and sphere map on sphere mesh:

- [NVidia Cube Map OpenGL](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cube_map_ogl_tutorial.html)
- [OpenGL Wiki Texturing a Sphere](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texturing_a_Sphere)
- [CSU Courses Texture](http://cse.csusb.edu/tong/courses/cs520/notes/texture.php)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you create the planet with two parameters for longitude and lattitude in this way (more or less):

```
for longitude from -Pi to Pi
    from latitude from -Pi/2 to Pi /2
        add vertex
    next
next
```

The simplest way to specify texture coordinates `u` and `v` for the vertex is to use the longitude / lattitude coordinates.

```
u = (longitude + Pi) / (2 Pi)
v = (Pi/2 - latitude) / Pi
```

This way you can use a texture like [this one](http://www.oera.net/how2/PlanetTexs/EarthMap_2500x1250.jpg). Note that the poles are compressed very much.

Comment: See also: [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection).

Comment: I have the image I want to use, what I don't know is how to code it in. What libraries to use, what functions, how they interact with the code I already have... things like that

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues: Maybe this one: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues first you must know which projection was used to generate the texture. Maybe if you show us we can make guesses. But probably is what Nico Schertler told you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by what projection was used to generate the texture. I haven't generated the texture, that's what I'm hoping to accomplish.